# Multicolor cursor in X

Tags: x11, mouse-cursor

X has the method XCreatePixmapCursor to create a cursor from a pixmap with a color depth of 1.  The foreground and background colors can be other than black and white, but there are only two colors.

Is there a way to create a multicolored cursor in X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the X Cursor Extensions. See the [XCURSOR(3)](http://www.xfree86.org/4.3.0/Xcursor.3.html) manpage and the X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h header file.